# java.net.ProtocolException: HTTP method DELETE doesn't support output

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, jersey-client

I am having this error while using `jersey-client-1.19`. All the googling I have done points to a bug or unnecessary limitation in HttpUrlConnection, especially in `java 7`.
I have been advised by some to move to java 8, I am not ready for that now.
I have already heard suggestions of transferring all my parameters to **path** but this can not work for me as the API requires me to pass certain authentication details as a `json` request body. 
I have already looked at several answers related to this question including [How do Jersey-client and Apache HTTP Client compare?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18570206/how-do-jersey-client-and-apache-http-client-compare). which suggests explicitely defining Apache's httpclient for `jersey`. So I thought there should be a standard integration of `jersey-client-1.19` with Apache httpclient in the back which is indeed confirmed by **Paul Sandoz** [answer](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Error-HTTP-method-DELETE-doesn-t-support-output-td4513829.html). However all the links he has offered there are down.
Does anyone know of any such integration or alternatively how I can just resolve this issue?

Comment: you should not include a body in a DELETE request, it won't work well with all servers. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334776/servlets-3-1-how-to-handle-body-in-delete-request/30335044#30335044

Comment: @bayou.io, thanks for the link. But am writing a client for a REST service that picks auth data from the request body, even for the DELETE operation. So all I need right now is how I can make it work.

Comment: @egima Did you find solution for the same? I am having same problem.

Comment: @SaurabhGadariya I had totally forgotten about this thread, since you woke it up, I have posted what worked for me as the answer. hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who still faces this problem, I am adding the hot-fix that worked for me. Basically, we resolved to send HTTP DELETE requests as POST to enable us to add a request body, with an additional `{"delete":true}` field in the JSON body. This will only work if it is the same team that is working on the REST service or if you are in position to add the corresponding check in the backend.